# Installing Ubuntu Desktop Error

Tags: software-installation, remote-desktop, tasksel

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop using `tasksel` utility but I got some errors.

```
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied
tasksel: debconf failed to run
```

Comment: You hae to run it as 'root'.

Comment: After running as root it shows:   


tasksel: apt-get failed (100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good!
If you're having the same error try this.

sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Glad it worked Steve. 1 upvote for the answer. In 2 days you can accept your own answer ( and please do, so users can see the question is resolved ).

Comment: Sure I will, thanks.